# Character Encoding Problem

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am trying to transfer a website from A to B. Unfortunately, I am having some sort of character encoding issue. I will go through what I doing. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out where the encoding is missing.

1) Generate SQL from original database. [A php script loops through the tables in the database constructing the SQL + insert data.]

2) Save SQL to a file

3) Run SQL on new host. SQL queries start with "SET NAMES 'utf8'"

4) Look at table in phpmyadmin : Currencies Display fine - table collation is utf8_general

5) Run CMS page - Currencies appear as � and ?.? [Page has the following encoding. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`]

6) Run original page which is identical and the currencies display fine.

This is where I am stuck really. As both the old and new site have identical files then surely this points to the database as being the sticking point... however phpMyAdmin is showing these characters just fine.. i'm confused. Any ideas?

Comment: if it is only problem with currency then try to use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CMS should also use `SET NAMES 'utf8'` when connecting to the database.
Maybe the default encoding is another one on the new server.

Answer (score 0):

The first what I'd check out is the encoding of the source code file. If it is encoded in Windows-1250 (cp1250) the source code will generate SQL and save it in Windows-1250 encoded file. So the characters could be messed up right in this .sql file - check it by opening in some text editor.

Also when saving SQL to .sql file - how do You do this? With headers and download or by fwrite function?

Another thing can be that when creating the .sql with SQL queries You do not set names to utf8 so the SQL being generated is not in UTF8... Check this also..